# What's wrong instance Functor Int where

Tags: haskell

What's wrong instance Functor Int where

```
instance Functor Int where
  fmap f a = f a
```

Expected kind ...

I can't make monad int , applicative int, functor int

Comment: On of the slightly more confusing things with `Functor`, `Applicative` and `Monad` is that the type you give it actually has to have kind `* -> *` - it needs to be expecting a type variable. In vanilla Haskell, kinds are simply inferred. Looking at the `Functor` class, you'll notice that `f` is always applied to a type variable. That let's the compiler infer that `f` has kind `* -> *`. That means things like `Maybe`, lists, `IO`, etc. NOT `Bool`, `Int`, `()`, etc.

Comment: [`Identity`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Functor-Identity.html) has functor/applicative/monad instances similar to this. For example, `runIdentity (fmap (+ 5) (pure 2 :: Identity Int)) == 7`.

Answer (score 9):

What is so interesting about `Maybe a`, `[a]`, `Either e a`, `IO a`? The type takes an additional parameter. That is, `Maybe` on its own isn't a type. You have to use another type e.g. `Int` to actually get a type: `Maybe Int`.

Let's have a look at `Functor`'s definition:

```
class Functor f where
    fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
              --        ^^^    ^^^
```

Whatever you use for `f` must be able to use a type. And `Int Int` or `Int ()` is not a type, because `Int` is already at kind `*`. You cannot construct another type by applying `Int` on something else.

`Maybe` on the other hand is of kind `* -> *`. It takes a type (e.g. `Double`) and returns a type, `Maybe Double`:

```
-- using pseudo kind-signatures
Maybe        :: * -> *
Double       :: *
Maybe Double ::      *
```

All that because our `f` takes an `a` in the signature of `fmap`.

So no. You cannot make any regular type (of kind `*`)  an instance of `Functor`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Functor f where
    fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

functor `f` maps types to types - it maps `a` to `f a` and `b` to `f b`. That means f can't be a concrete type such as Int; it has to be a type that takes another type as a parameter. You can think of `f` as a function on types.